# Gulp VS2015 .Net5

Tags: asp.net, gulp, project.json

Im trying to learn Gulp and have been unable to successfully run tasks via the Task Run Explorer.  No tasks appear and the Explorer shows the error: `Failed to load, see output window for more information.`  When checking the output window it appears that it cant find my project.json.

```
Failed to run "F:\Projects\NewInventory\src\NewInventory\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
Error: Cannot find module ' ./project.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\NewInventory\src\NewInventory\gulpfile.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

Failed to run "F:\Projects\NewInventory\src\NewInventory\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
Error: Cannot find module ' ./project.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\NewInventory\src\NewInventory\gulpfile.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

However, I also created a new .Net5 web application from scratch and compared with my current project to ensure that the project.json was in the correct directory location.

My project.json is as follows:

```
 "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-NewInventory-f5a8bab7-e95b-485b-97e9-9a072438b107",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Binder": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  },
  "configurations": {
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "1.11.2",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "del": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.10",
    "npm-check-updates": "2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    project = require("./project.json");

var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var del = require('del');
var project = require(' ./project.json');
var lib = project.webroot + '/lib';

var paths = {
    webroot: "./" + project.webroot + "/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task('default', ['bower:install'], function () {
    return;
});

gulp.task('bower:install', ['clean'], function () {
    return bower({
        directory: lib
    });
});

gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
    del(lib, done);
});

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

Comment: Can you add your gulpfile to the post please? It looks like a `require` statement has an incorrect path; `at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\NewInventory\src\NewInventory\gulpfile.js:12:15)`

Comment: @RDay Added.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the error by removing the line

```
var project = require(' ./project.json');
```

The space at the beginning of the path literal means it is not pointing at project.json. There is a line before doing what you need it to do;

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    project = require("./project.json"); <---- This is doing what you expected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution.  Surprised that no one offered a suggestion for so many days and that I had to put up a bounty.

Comment: It seems odd to me too but I'm glad I could help. I just started with gulp the other day myself.